# Is it possible to dynamically switch database table in query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Im quite new to C# programming. I have a situation where I need to read data dynamically from database tables and I need to switch tables depending of category. Data that I read from tables is always same, just tables are different.
Is it possible to dynamically switch database table in query?

I made an abstract code to explain My thoughts:

```
                    var userPost = if(Category == "News"){ db.News } else { db.Sport}
                    .Include(x => x.Popular)
                    .Include(x => x.Popular.Category)
                    .Where(x => x.User.Id == userId)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                    .ProjectTo<PostViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Thank You ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ORM is mapping both tables to the same types, you should be able to do this:

```
var userPost = (Category == "News" ? db.News : db.Sport)
                .Include(x => x.Popular)
                .Include(x => x.Popular.Category)
                .Where(x => x.User.Id == userId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                .ProjectTo<PostViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Or, perhaps a bit more readable:

```
var table = (Category == "News" ? db.News : db.Sport);

var userPost = table
                .Include(x => x.Popular)
                .Include(x => x.Popular.Category)
                .Where(x => x.User.Id == userId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                .ProjectTo<PostViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
```

If you have more than 2 tables you want to multiplex, you might want to split the selection logic out into another method:

```
internal IQueryable<ROWTYPE> SelectTable(string category)
{
    switch (category)
    {
        case "News": return db.News;
        case "Sport": return db.Sport;
        case "Arts": return db.Arts;
        default: throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported category: " + category);
    }
} 



var table = SelectTable(Category);

var userPost = table
                .Include(x => x.Popular)
                .Include(x => x.Popular.Category)
                .Where(x => x.User.Id == userId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                .ProjectTo<PostViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking with the ternary operator; you beat me to it :p

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. Is it possible even with 3 categories?
Will test it :)

Comment: @JLRishe Ok, cool :) Could You please explaine more about that IQuerable<ROWTYPE>? What this ROWTYPE is?

Comment: @Aaron It's whatever class is mapped to the rows in your table. I don't know what class that is in your case, so I've indicated ROWTYPE as a placeholder for that.